# Where in the world does "a lift" mean "a ride in the car"?

Tags: expressions, semantics, geography, doubled-words

In the United States and Canada, when someone asks you for "a lift" or you offer "a lift", you are speaking about riding in a car with them.

However, in England and other places, a "lift" is an elevator. "Taking a lift" means "taking an elevator".

Where else in the world does "a lift" not refer to, or cannot be construed as "a ride"?

Comment: Offering someone a lift means "a ride in a car," or more accurately, "transport to the place the driver's already going" in the UK too.

Comment: In the US, the idiomatic phrase is *getting a lift*.  *Taking a lift* is not commonly used though there would be nothing wrong or misunderstood here, where elevators are called elevators.

Comment: *When we were putting up our new office building, we were a bit short of money, so we were happy when the Otis elevator people gave us a lift.*

Comment: Since your question does not specify language, I’ll just add that _lift_ is also the (or at least _a_) common term for a free ride in someone else’s car to wherever you’re going in both Danish, Swedish, and Norwegian. It does not mean ‘elevator’ in Danish or Swedish (who use _elevator_ and _hiss_ respectively), though it can be used for an elevator in Norwegian (more commonly _heis_).  It does also mean a baby lift or a ski lift in both Danish and Swedish, though Norwegian uses _heis_ for this as well.

Comment: You seem to be under the (quite common) misapprehension that a word cannot have more than one meaning. _A lift_ means (among other things) **both** a device for moving between floors and a ride in a car.

Comment: -1 *However, in England and other places, a "lift" is an elevator. "Taking a lift" means "taking an elevator".* -- No.

Comment: @Kris actually, it does. Walk into an office building, tell the guy at the front desk that you're going to "take a lift up" and then ask him if you said something that made sense.

Comment: That's a context for that meaning. Not in the context of traveling by road. Also, one would say *take **the** lift*, in the context of an 'elevator' and *take lift* in the context of a 'ride'. All in the same geographic (UK, other).

Comment: Actually, one would usually say "get a lift" in terms of a ride.

Comment: 'Where else in the world does "a lift" not refer to, or cannot be construed as "a ride"?' demands that 'In England, "a lift" does not refer to, or cannot be construed as, "a ride".' This is not true. The word is polysemous, in the UK as well as elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the UK *a lift* is by far the most common word for "taking somebody somewhere in a car". *A ride* is unusual in this sense, except perhaps where the purpose is to enjoy the journey rather than to get somewhere.

My impression (as a Brit) is that in the US *a ride* is more common than *a lift* for taking somebody in a car.

Comment: This is largely true, but there's also a phrase "take X for a ride", which means to give someone false or misleading information.

Comment: True, @CharlesBurge, but if it is relevant (which I doubt) it confirms my side-note, that "a ride" is about the journey rather than the destination.

Answer (score 0):

In South Africa asking someone for a lift produces two possible responses: "Sure where are you going?"or "I'm going to ... ?", the latter implies that, if that helps hop in and I'll drop you off along the way.

Answer (score 0):

In sailing terms a “lift” is when the wind changes direction so that you can now sail directly to your destination, whereas before it was directly into the wind, which you cannot sail. The opposite of “lift” is “knock”, where you the wind has shifted to now be blowing where you want to go and were previously going.

Getting a lift in modern usage seems to be an unexpected offer or hopeful request of being taken somewhere, and doesn’t seem to be used in any other context.

I wonder if “getting/giving a lift” and “being knocked off course” are both nautical terms.
Getting a lift in sailing is what everyone wants, are extremely helpful, and take you directly where you need to go.

I’m unable to verify this, though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I remember 'lift' being used most frequently in the 1950's and '60's as referring to driving another person to their destination. Now days it it more frequent to ask if they need 'a ride' to their destination. Somewhere in between then and now the terminology has shifted.....but why? Why was the term 'lift' used in the first place?

Comment: If you have an anecdote rather than an answer, it is preferred that you just post a comment.